# Add Modal to Body element

Tags: vmware-clarity

When I add clarity modal component  to my component HTML template I find it located under my component DOM all the time. If my component's template is an SVG I don't see the modal dialog shown in the UI because it is inside of SVG DOM. In this case it is best to add the modal dialog to the body element. Libs such as ngx-bootstrap or bootstrap-ui allow adding modal to the body as an option but i don't see this option in Clarity Modal. Any advice on how to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.